# How do i add a mclmcrrt.lib or (.lib) file when compiling with g++ Compiler

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++, g++

I have a algorithm code which uses matlab library(mclmcrrt.lib) it compiles well in my vc++ compiler when i add that library to it.

My question is if i want to compile it on Linux g++ compiler how should i link the library can i use it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a Linux version of the library from matlab - Compiled code does not transfer across operating systems